# How to get the internet speed in android

Tags: android, network-programming, android-wifi, connectivity

Help me to find the internet speed in android. I went through many questions which are asked in stack overflow. But I didn't get proper solution to my question. Below code will be used to check the wifi speed.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
currentNetworkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed()
return currentNetworkSpeed;
```

But I want to get the speed of internet in my phone might be 3G/2G/4G. And the questions that were answered are 2 to 5 years back. is there any new technique to find the speed of internet?

Comment: before down voting please comment ur answers if you know already.

Answer (score 1):

**Network Connection Class**

> Network Connection Class is an Android library that allows you to figure out the quality of the current user's internet connection. The connection gets classified into several "Connection Classes" that make it easy to develop against. The library does this by listening to the existing internet traffic done by your app and notifying you when the user's connection quality changes. Developers can then use this Connection Class information and adjust the application's behaviour (request lower quality images or video, throttle type-ahead, etc).

Find Link of Library [here](https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class)

Answer (score 0):

For *Mobile Data Link* I am afraid that you can only check [TelefonyManager.getNetworkType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkType%28%29) to determine the current Mobile Data Link type. You should then aproximate to actual speed by link type (i.e. for **GPRS** up to 128 kbps, for **EDGE** up to 236.8 kpbs, for **3G** up to 2 Mbps, for **HSDPA** up to 7.2 Mbps). Take into consideration that this is only an aproximation. Your could be conneting using **HSDPA** but your carrier limiting the top speed to 2 Mbps.

Comment: I need an exact value.